# How to sort date and time in an ascending and descending order per day and create a designated column for the sorted dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns ('Date (UTC)', 'X' and 'Y')

```
        Date (UTC)           X           Y
0    2020-01-01 00:00:00   2.4497     30.8736  
1    2020-01-01 01:00:00   3.4148     30.1853  
2    2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.6045     32.4904  
3    2020-01-01 03:00:00   1.7704     32.5102  
4    2020-01-01 04:00:00  -7.1172     25.1757  
...                  ...      ...         ...  
5784 2020-08-22 18:23:59 -15.0077    -11.4135  
5785 2020-08-22 19:23:59 -13.9187    -12.5453  
5786 2020-08-22 20:23:59 -13.5544    -14.0992  
5787 2020-08-22 21:23:59 -10.0891    -17.9784  
5788 2020-08-22 22:23:59  -6.8927    -16.5153
```

and I would like the output to have additional columns such that:

- the sorted date and time in an ASCENDING order PER DAY (wrt TIME) with its corresponding X and Y isadded to the dataframe
- the sorted date and time in DESCENDING order PER DAY (wrt TIME) with its corresponding X and Y is added to the dataframe
- the difference between the DESCENDING X values and ASCENDING X values per row is reflected in the X_Difference column (X_Dsc-X_Asc)
- the difference between the DESCENDING Y values and ASCENDING Y values per row is reflected in the Y_Difference column (Y_Dsc-Y_Asc)

as seen in the sample output below that I've made in a worksheet,

```
             Date (UTC)        X        Y    Date_Asc  Time_Asc    X_Asc  \
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00   2.4497  30.8736  2020-01-01  00:00:00   2.4497   
1   2020-01-01 01:00:00   3.4148  30.1853  2020-01-01  01:00:00   3.4148   
2   2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.6045  32.4904  2020-01-01  02:00:00   2.6045   
3   2020-01-01 03:00:00   1.7704  32.5102  2020-01-01  03:00:00   1.7704   
4   2020-01-01 04:00:00  -7.1172  25.1757  2020-01-01  04:00:00  -7.1172   
5   2020-01-01 05:00:00 -15.4088  24.4337  2020-01-01  05:00:00 -15.4088   
6   2020-01-01 06:00:00 -27.3290  29.6146  2020-01-01  06:00:00 -27.3290   
7   2020-01-01 07:00:00 -35.1151  34.9471  2020-01-01  07:00:00 -35.1151   
8   2020-01-01 08:00:00 -42.1931  40.1325  2020-01-01  08:00:00 -42.1931   
9   2020-01-01 09:00:00 -38.2346  38.4806  2020-01-01  09:00:00 -38.2346   
10  2020-01-01 10:00:00 -34.8297  33.7403  2020-01-01  10:00:00 -34.8297   
11  2020-01-01 11:00:00 -34.1078  33.0918  2020-01-01  11:00:00 -34.1078   
12  2020-01-01 12:00:00 -35.3642  30.9796  2020-01-01  12:00:00 -35.3642   
13  2020-01-01 13:00:00 -33.9252  30.8584  2020-01-01  13:00:00 -33.9252   
14  2020-01-01 14:00:00 -32.2875  32.0968  2020-01-01  14:00:00 -32.2875   
15  2020-01-01 15:00:00 -28.5886  30.5157  2020-01-01  15:00:00 -28.5886   
16  2020-01-01 16:00:00 -26.2631  28.5850  2020-01-01  16:00:00 -26.2631   
17  2020-01-01 17:00:00 -24.9291  27.7629  2020-01-01  17:00:00 -24.9291   
18  2020-01-01 18:00:00 -20.9242  28.1081  2020-01-01  18:00:00 -20.9242   
19  2020-01-01 19:00:00 -19.3358  28.4239  2020-01-01  19:00:00 -19.3358   
20  2020-01-01 20:00:00 -18.8498  27.5946  2020-01-01  20:00:00 -18.8498   
21  2020-01-01 21:00:00 -17.6154  27.5777  2020-01-01  21:00:00 -17.6154   
22  2020-01-01 22:00:00 -17.5111  27.6045  2020-01-01  22:00:00 -17.5111   
23  2020-01-01 23:00:00 -17.8218  30.6621  2020-01-01  23:00:00 -17.8218   
24  2020-01-02 00:00:00 -18.2261  32.9834  2020-01-02  00:00:00 -18.2261   
25  2020-01-02 01:00:00 -19.1256  33.9799  2020-01-02  01:00:00 -19.1256   
26  2020-01-02 02:00:00 -22.5682  33.0480  2020-01-02  02:00:00 -22.5682   
27  2020-01-02 03:00:00 -28.0774  34.2475  2020-01-02  03:00:00 -28.0774   
28  2020-01-02 04:00:00 -36.0161  28.1081  2020-01-02  04:00:00 -36.0161   
29  2020-01-02 05:00:00 -39.8972  32.2631  2020-01-02  05:00:00 -39.8972   
30  2020-01-02 06:00:00 -37.7294  33.6043  2020-01-02  06:00:00 -37.7294   
31  2020-01-02 07:00:00 -29.6897  31.3064  2020-01-02  07:00:00 -29.6897   
32  2020-01-02 08:00:00 -18.4394  26.5454  2020-01-02  08:00:00 -18.4394   
33  2020-01-02 09:00:00 -14.2478  29.2039  2020-01-02  09:00:00 -14.2478   
34  2020-01-02 10:00:00 -11.6615  26.4184  2020-01-02  10:00:00 -11.6615   
35  2020-01-02 11:00:00  -8.2162  26.8972  2020-01-02  11:00:00  -8.2162   
36  2020-01-02 12:00:00  -4.4618  25.9781  2020-01-02  12:00:00  -4.4618   
37  2020-01-02 13:00:00  -2.4028  26.8930  2020-01-02  13:00:00  -2.4028   
38  2020-01-02 14:00:00  -1.1351  27.6698  2020-01-02  14:00:00  -1.1351   
39  2020-01-02 15:00:00   2.3592  27.3872  2020-01-02  15:00:00   2.3592   
40  2020-01-02 16:00:00   4.5456  29.5461  2020-01-02  16:00:00   4.5456   
41  2020-01-02 17:00:00   6.6295  31.3422  2020-01-02  17:00:00   6.6295   
42  2020-01-02 18:00:00   7.6197  32.0937  2020-01-02  18:00:00   7.6197   
43  2020-01-02 19:00:00   8.6444  31.9142  2020-01-02  19:00:00   8.6444   
44  2020-01-02 20:00:00   8.1178  31.5972  2020-01-02  20:00:00   8.1178   
45  2020-01-02 21:00:00   7.0879  29.9666  2020-01-02  21:00:00   7.0879   
46  2020-01-02 22:00:00   5.9424  29.3420  2020-01-02  22:00:00   5.9424   
47  2020-01-02 23:00:00   4.1502  31.9366  2020-01-02  23:00:00   4.1502   

     Y_Asc   Date_Desc  Time_Desc   X_Dsc    Y_Dsc     X_Difference  \
0   30.8736  2020-01-01  23:00:00 -17.8218  30.6621      -20.2715   
1   30.1853  2020-01-01  22:00:00 -17.5111  27.6045      -20.9259   
2   32.4904  2020-01-01  21:00:00 -17.6154  27.5777      -20.2199   
3   32.5102  2020-01-01  20:00:00 -18.8498  27.5946      -20.6202   
4   25.1757  2020-01-01  19:00:00 -19.3358  28.4239      -12.2186   
5   24.4337  2020-01-01  18:00:00 -20.9242  28.1081       -5.5154   
6   29.6146  2020-01-01  17:00:00 -24.9291  27.7629        2.3999   
7   34.9471  2020-01-01  16:00:00 -26.2631  28.5850        8.8520   
8   40.1325  2020-01-01  15:00:00 -28.5886  30.5157       13.6045   
9   38.4806  2020-01-01  14:00:00 -32.2875  32.0968        5.9471   
10  33.7403  2020-01-01  13:00:00 -33.9252  30.8584        0.9045   
11  33.0918  2020-01-01  12:00:00 -35.3642  30.9796       -1.2564   
12  30.9796  2020-01-01  11:00:00 -34.1078  33.0918        1.2564   
13  30.8584  2020-01-01  10:00:00 -34.8297  33.7403       -0.9045   
14  32.0968  2020-01-01  09:00:00 -38.2346  38.4806       -5.9471   
15  30.5157  2020-01-01  08:00:00 -42.1931  40.1325      -13.6045   
16  28.5850  2020-01-01  07:00:00 -35.1151  34.9471       -8.8520   
17  27.7629  2020-01-01  06:00:00 -27.3290  29.6146       -2.3999   
18  28.1081  2020-01-01  05:00:00 -15.4088  24.4337        5.5154   
19  28.4239  2020-01-01  04:00:00  -7.1172  25.1757       12.2186   
20  27.5946  2020-01-01  03:00:00   1.7704  32.5102       20.6202   
21  27.5777  2020-01-01  02:00:00   2.6045  32.4904       20.2199   
22  27.6045  2020-01-01  01:00:00   3.4148  30.1853       20.9259   
23  30.6621  2020-01-01  00:00:00   2.4497  30.8736       20.2715   
24  32.9834  2020-01-02  23:00:00   4.1502  31.9366       22.3763   
25  33.9799  2020-01-02  22:00:00   5.9424  29.3420       25.0680   
26  33.0480  2020-01-02  21:00:00   7.0879  29.9666       29.6561   
27  34.2475  2020-01-02  20:00:00   8.1178  31.5972       36.1952   
28  28.1081  2020-01-02  19:00:00   8.6444  31.9142       44.6605   
29  32.2631  2020-01-02  18:00:00   7.6197  32.0937       47.5169   
30  33.6043  2020-01-02  17:00:00   6.6295  31.3422       44.3589   
31  31.3064  2020-01-02  16:00:00   4.5456  29.5461       34.2353   
32  26.5454  2020-01-02  15:00:00   2.3592  27.3872       20.7986   
33  29.2039  2020-01-02  14:00:00  -1.1351  27.6698       13.1127   
34  26.4184  2020-01-02  13:00:00  -2.4028  26.8930        9.2587   
35  26.8972  2020-01-02  12:00:00  -4.4618  25.9781        3.7544   
36  25.9781  2020-01-02  11:00:00  -8.2162  26.8972       -3.7544   
37  26.8930  2020-01-02  10:00:00 -11.6615  26.4184       -9.2587   
38  27.6698  2020-01-02  09:00:00 -14.2478  29.2039      -13.1127   
39  27.3872  2020-01-02  08:00:00 -18.4394  26.5454      -20.7986   
40  29.5461  2020-01-02  07:00:00 -29.6897  31.3064      -34.2353   
41  31.3422  2020-01-02  06:00:00 -37.7294  33.6043      -44.3589   
42  32.0937  2020-01-02  05:00:00 -39.8972  32.2631      -47.5169   
43  31.9142  2020-01-02  04:00:00 -36.0161  28.1081      -44.6605   
44  31.5972  2020-01-02  03:00:00 -28.0774  34.2475      -36.1952   
45  29.9666  2020-01-02  02:00:00 -22.5682  33.0480      -29.6561   
46  29.3420  2020-01-02  01:00:00 -19.1256  33.9799      -25.0680   
47  31.9366  2020-01-02  00:00:00 -18.2261  32.9834      -22.3763   

       Y_Difference  
0        -0.2115  
1        -2.5808  
2        -4.9127  
3        -4.9156  
4         3.2482  
5         3.6744  
6        -1.8517  
7        -6.3621  
8        -9.6168  
9        -6.3838  
10       -2.8819  
11       -2.1122  
12        2.1122  
13        2.8819  
14        6.3838  
15        9.6168  
16        6.3621  
17        1.8517  
18       -3.6744  
19       -3.2482  
20        4.9156  
21        4.9127  
22        2.5808  
23        0.2115  
24       -1.0468  
25       -4.6379  
26       -3.0814  
27       -2.6503  
28        3.8061  
29       -0.1694  
30       -2.2621  
31       -1.7603  
32        0.8418  
33       -1.5341  
34        0.4746  
35       -0.9191  
36        0.9191  
37       -0.4746  
38        1.5341  
39       -0.8418  
40        1.7603  
41        2.2621  
42        0.1694  
43       -3.8061  
44        2.6503  
45        3.0814  
46        4.6379  
47        1.0468
```

I tried coding it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(i, parse_dates=[" Date (UTC)"])

ascending_data = pd.DataFrame()
ascending_data = df.sort_values(by=[" Date (UTC)"])
ascending_data['Date_Asc'] = [d.date() for d in ascending_data[' Date (UTC)']]
ascending_data['Time_Asc'] = [d.time() for d in ascending_data[' Date (UTC)']]
ascending_data['X_Asc'] = df['X']
ascending_data['Y_Asc'] = df['Y']
print(ascending_data)

descending_data = pd.DataFrame()
descending_data = df.sort_values(by=[" Date (UTC)"], ascending=False)
descending_data['Date_Desc'] = [d.date() for d in descending_data[' Date (UTC)']]
descending_data['Time_Desc'] = [d.time() for d in descending_data[' Date (UTC)']]
descending_data['X_Desc'] = df['X']
descending_data['Y_Desc'] = df['Y']
descending_data = descending_data.reset_index(drop=True)
print(descending_data)
        
result = pd.concat([ascending_data, descending_data], axis=1)
result['X_Diff'] = result['X_Desc'] - result['X_Asc']
result['Y_Diff'] = result['Y_Desc'] - result['Y_Asc']
print(result)
```

but the result is...

```
              Date (UTC)     X           Y      Date_Asc   Time_Asc   X_Asc  \
0    2020-01-01 00:00:00   2.4497     30.8736  2020-01-01  00:00:00   2.4497   
1    2020-01-01 01:00:00   3.4148     30.1853  2020-01-01  01:00:00   3.4148   
2    2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.6045     32.4904  2020-01-01  02:00:00   2.6045   
3    2020-01-01 03:00:00   1.7704     32.5102  2020-01-01  03:00:00   1.7704   
4    2020-01-01 04:00:00  -7.1172     25.1757  2020-01-01  04:00:00  -7.1172   
...                  ...      ...         ...         ...       ...      ...   
5784 2020-08-22 18:23:59 -15.0077    -11.4135  2020-08-22  18:23:59 -15.0077   
5785 2020-08-22 19:23:59 -13.9187    -12.5453  2020-08-22  19:23:59 -13.9187   
5786 2020-08-22 20:23:59 -13.5544    -14.0992  2020-08-22  20:23:59 -13.5544   
5787 2020-08-22 21:23:59 -10.0891    -17.9784  2020-08-22  21:23:59 -10.0891   
5788 2020-08-22 22:23:59  -6.8927    -16.5153  2020-08-22  22:23:59  -6.8927   

       Y_Asc          Date (UTC)      X           Y      Date_Dsc  Time_Dsc  \
0     30.8736 2020-08-22 22:23:59  -6.8927    -16.5153  2020-08-22  22:23:59   
1     30.1853 2020-08-22 21:23:59 -10.0891    -17.9784  2020-08-22  21:23:59   
2     32.4904 2020-08-22 20:23:59 -13.5544    -14.0992  2020-08-22  20:23:59   
3     32.5102 2020-08-22 19:23:59 -13.9187    -12.5453  2020-08-22  19:23:59   
4     25.1757 2020-08-22 18:23:59 -15.0077    -11.4135  2020-08-22  18:23:59   
...       ...                 ...      ...         ...         ...       ...   
5784 -11.4135 2020-01-01 04:00:00  -7.1172     25.1757  2020-01-01  04:00:00   
5785 -12.5453 2020-01-01 03:00:00   1.7704     32.5102  2020-01-01  03:00:00   
5786 -14.0992 2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.6045     32.4904  2020-01-01  02:00:00   
5787 -17.9784 2020-01-01 01:00:00   3.4148     30.1853  2020-01-01  01:00:00   
5788 -16.5153 2020-01-01 00:00:00   2.4497     30.8736  2020-01-01  00:00:00   

       X_Dsc    Y_Dsc     X_Diff    Y_Diff  
0     -6.8927 -16.5153   -9.3424  -47.3889  
1    -10.0891 -17.9784  -13.5039  -48.1637  
2    -13.5544 -14.0992  -16.1589  -46.5896  
3    -13.9187 -12.5453  -15.6891  -45.0555  
4    -15.0077 -11.4135   -7.8905  -36.5892  
...       ...      ...       ...       ...  
5784  -7.1172  25.1757    7.8905   36.5892  
5785   1.7704  32.5102   15.6891   45.0555  
5786   2.6045  32.4904   16.1589   46.5896  
5787   3.4148  30.1853   13.5039   48.1637  
5788   2.4497  30.8736    9.3424   47.3889
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @NYCCoder I've tried sorting with ascending and descending but the problem is I don't know how to make the descending part on per day basis within the 1-hr intervals. I have edited the question with my trial in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new columns with date and time from your original date column:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date (UTC)'].dt.day
df['Time'] = df['Date (UTC)'].dt.time
```

However I would not recommend to name the columns after the sorting order, because imagine having two columns: `Date Asc` and `Date Desc` - it makes no sense as the data cannot be sorted in ascending and descending order at the same time unless it is a single value series, but even then the two columns would contain the same data. So you should rather call the columns `Date` and `Time`, and if you need to sort your entire dataframe permanently use:

```
df.sort_values(['Date', 'Time'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

If you then need to calculate the differences between the coordinates of the data sorted in different orders you can do it this way:

```
# the difference between the DESCENDING X values and ASCENDING X values per row is reflected in the X_Difference column (X_Dsc-X_Asc)

df['X_Dsc-X_Asc'] = df.sort_values(['Date', 'Time'], ascending=False).X.sub(df.sort_values(['Date', 'Time'], ascending=True).X)


# the difference between the DESCENDING Y values and ASCENDING Y values per row is reflected in the Y_Difference column (Y_Dsc-Y_Asc)

df['Y_Dsc-Y_Asc'] = df.sort_values(['Date', 'Time'], ascending=False).Y.sub(df.sort_values(['Date', 'Time'], ascending=True).Y)
```

So as you can see the order of the data in the columns does not matter, because you can cast your dataframe in any order to perform column-wise or row-wise operations and save the results in a new column, but then you will have to make sure that the order of data in the new column matches the order of the dataframe, ie. if the dataframe was not sorted, but the new column is sorted you will have a row-wise mismatch.

Comment: hi @mac13k thanks for your answer. i tried what you suggested but it gave me 0s in the difference output

Comment: This suggests that asc and desc sorting returned the same series. You need to take a closer look why. Run the two sorts separately and compare the results.